# Use string delimiter to parse integer

Tags: java, regex, string

I have input in the form of (x, y), where x and y are integers. For example, (10, 10). I need to parse out the integers from the input. Here's my code:

```
String dilims = "(,) ";
String[] xy = s.split(dilims);
```

With this code however the tokens in xy was "(10" and "10)", instead of "10", "10". Why would it be that "," and whitespace is recognized as delimiter but "(" and ")" are not? Please advise.

Thank you,
M

Comment: Did you read `split` documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-? If so do you know what regex is and what `(` and `)` represents there? Also `split` is probably not what you want to use since it will create empty string at start because of `(`.

Comment: `split()` works with regular expressions, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: Just for the record, the OP seems to have tagged this with `regex` so I presume he knows they use regexes. Reading up on regexes in Java may be useful. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: You have to use a character class. You are looking for all four of those characters in that order to split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` is not what you want to use (at least not for this form of input) since because of `(` at start it will create empty string in result array, just like `"foo".split("f")` creates `["", "oo"]`.

Anyway since `split` takes regex as argument, with code

```
String[] xy = "(10, 10)".split("(,) ");
```

are not getting `10` `10` as result, but `(10` `10)` because `"(,) "` represents `", "` where `,` is placed in [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). So you are simply splitting on `", "`.

If you would like to split on `(` OR `)` OR `,` OR  you will need to escape `(` and `)` and use `|` which represents OR operator, so your regex could look like `"\\(|\\)|,| "`, but as already mentioned for this input it is bad idea.

If your data is always in form `(xxx, yyy)` then consider removing first `(` and `)` (for instance with `substring`) and then split on `", "` like

```
String dilims = ", ";
String[] xy = s.substring(1,s.length()-1).split(dilims);
```

---

You can also use Scanner which if it finds delimiter at start will ignore fact that first potential result is empty string, so for data like `foo` and delimiter `f` first result will be `oo`.

Delimiter also is written using regex. We can easily create one representing either `(` `)` `,`  (space) with little help of [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). It can look like `[(), ]` (inside character class `(` and `)` loses its special meaning so we don't need to escape it). But since there can be more then one delimiters one after another (`,` and `space`) and we don't need to treat empty string between them as one of results we need to let delimiter accept one or more of continuous characters. We can do it with `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

So your code can look like

```
String s = "(10, 10)";

Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
sc.useDelimiter("[(), ]+");

int x=sc.nextInt();
int y = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("x="+x);
System.out.println("y="+y);
```

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Updated my answer. Hope now it is OK.

Comment: Look's good, but I'd use the escape character for the space instead of a literal space.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Normally I would do it, but I don't want to introduce too many new things at once.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex to capture groups:

```
    String text = "(10, 10)";

    String patternString = "([-]*[0-9]+)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: You forgot about the negative integers, (-10,-10) is also a pair of Integer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really getting only (10,10) as input then you may try the below option:

```
String s ="(10,10)"; //Input String
String dilims = ","; 
s = s.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" ", ""); //replacing all unwanted
String[] xy = s.split(dilims);
```

O/p:-

```
10
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this split to split by non-number characters:

```
String[] xy = s.split("[^\\d-]+");
```

Comment: What if input is `(-10, 10)`?

Comment: Normally, I'd use a compiled pattern and a matcher to search for a class containing the integers and the dash character. But the OP insists on using split.

Comment: So you should probably use `split("[^\\d-]+")`.

Comment: @Pshemo The minus would be excluded if I was to use that.

Comment: And that is the idea, we want delimiter to be everything which is not digit or `-` so it could stay near `-10`.

Comment: Oh, yes I guess I got a bit mixed up.